# htaccess rewriterule parent folder only

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to change the rewrite rule to only apply to the current folder that the htaccess file is in

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1\.php
```

how do I change this to make that work?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restrict your pattern to only match characters other than `/`:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a limited number of known sub-directories I would do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (list|of|sub|dirs)
RewriteRule . - [s=1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1\.php
```

That skips the next 1 rule when the condition is true. You could change the `[s=1]` to match any number of rules you want to not apply to the sub-directories.